# Power set of string array(as input) in C#

Tags: c#, powerset

I want to create a power set function which accepts string[] as input and gives output as shown in the bottom under **EDIT1**.

I came across this

```
private static List<string> PowerSet(string[] input)
{
    int n = input.Length;
    // Power set contains 2^N subsets.
    int powerSetCount = 1 << n;
    var ans = new List<string>();

    for (int setMask = 0; setMask < powerSetCount; setMask++)
    {
        var s = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            // Checking whether i'th element of input collection should go to the current subset.
            if ((setMask & (1 << i)) > 0)
            {
                s.Append(input[i]);
            }
        }
        ans.Add(s.ToString());
    }

    return ans;
}
```

I can not use this function as

**EDIT1**

Above function gives me output for a set say {'a','b'} as

```
""
"a"
"b"
"ab"
```

I need the output to appear as

```
{}
{"a"}
{"b"}
{"a","b"}
```

Comment: Do you mean "params string[] args" as argument? Then you can use 1,2,3,...n input arguments. For each argument you can use your current implementation.

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: Are you really asking just about how to add items to list?

Answer (score 1):

You can use param keyword to send a set of string values as parameter. They can act as a string array as well. Here is a sample implementation.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var list = PowerSet("node1", "node2", "node3");
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private static List<string> PowerSet(params string[] input)
{
    if (input == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("input");
    }

    // Power set contains 2^N subsets.
    var powerSetCount = 1 << input.Length;

    var returnValue = new List<string>();

    for (var setMask = 0; setMask < powerSetCount; setMask++)
    {
        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
        {
            // Checking whether i'th element of input collection should go to the current subset.
            if ((setMask & (1 << i)) > 0)
                stringBuilder.Append(input[i]);
        }
        returnValue.Add(stringBuilder.ToString());
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: if number of elements int the input set increase it will be difficult to read the output. as the elements are adjacent without any space.